# Gas calculator jquery app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make changes to this application http://www.nextworldweb.co.uk/blog/2011/02/fuel-cost-calculator-with-code-js-jquery/ from miles to kilometros but is not working. I tried to change the average price of the gasoline to Chilean pesos ($550) and instead of showing gallons I just want to show litres.

Here is the HTML:

#### Inputs:

I am travelling
        
        miles

My car averages
        
        miles to the gallon

The current price for a litre is £

#### Results:

You will use approx.
        X
        gallons, or
        Z
        litres

Which will cost you:
        **£Y**

I have to include jQuery and this is the jQuery code used.

```
//called when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

  var fuelCostCalcer = {
    //define the input fields
    inputAr: new Array('miles', 'mpg', 'cost_per_litre'),

    //define the results fields
    resultAr: new Array('gallons_used', 'litres_used', 'total_cost'),

    //function to init object, set listeners, make first results
    init: function() {

      var $fi;
      //for each input field, add a change listener
      for (var i in this.inputAr) {
        $fi = $('#' + this.inputAr[i] + '_fi'); //select the field as jQuery object
        //bind the events, triggered when value changes
        $fi.bind('keyup change', this.doCalc);
      }
      //trigger change on the last field, to init the result
      $fi.trigger('change');
    },

    //triggerd by field value change
    doCalc: function(eventObj) {
      /* CHECK AND SET THE INPUT VARS */
      //the inputVars obj
      var inputVars = {};
      //do input validation
      var isValid = true;
      for (var i in fuelCostCalcer.inputAr) {
        var fiId = fuelCostCalcer.inputAr[i]; //get field ID
        var val = $('#' + fiId + '_fi').val(); //get the value from the input field
        //if is in valid value
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(val)) || val < 0 || val > 10000000) {
          isValid = false;
          break;
        }
        //else set as property in this object
        else
          inputVars[fiId] = val;
      }

      /* SET THE RESULT VARS */
      //the resultVars obj
      var resultVars = {};
      //if inputs are valid then calculate the results
      if (isValid) {
        var milesPerLitre = inputVars['mpg'] / 4.54609188; //4.5 is the litres in a gallon
        resultVars['gallons_used'] = inputVars['miles'] / inputVars['mpg'];
        resultVars['litres_used'] = inputVars['miles'] / milesPerLitre;
        resultVars['total_cost'] = resultVars['litres_used'] * inputVars['cost_per_litre'];
      }
      //not valid, so set all result vars to 0
      else {
        for (var i in fuelCostCalcer.resultAr)
          resultVars[fuelCostCalcer.resultAr[i]] = 0;
      }

      /* SET RESULTS IN TO HTML */
      for (var i in fuelCostCalcer.resultAr) {
        var laId = fuelCostCalcer.resultAr[i]; //get label/span ID
        $('#' + laId + '_la').text(resultVars[laId].toFixed(2));
      }
    }
  };

  fuelCostCalcer.init();
});
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML as well?  Either include it in your question, or you can set up a fiddle and then share that : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work on JSFiddle.

Then I don't know what's going wrong for you.
Maybe your elements in the html code aren't defined with the good ids?

By the way, I kept the function-object fuelCostCalcer out of document.ready and just kept the init inside, because your object lives all along with the html page.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  fuelCostCalcer.init();
});
var fuelCostCalcer = {
   ...
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tds84qp1/

Let me know.

Comment: That looks good, however I need to transform the miles into Kilometers so is still giving my the wrong information for the total cost. :s